# creating multiple actors at once

Tags: java, graph, parallel-processing, akka

I am using the AKKA framework with its Java API for creating an actor system. Here is a gist of the actors. The actors are responsible for processing nodes in a graph. For nodes on the same level in the graph , processing can be done in parallel and hence I need to spawn actors paralelly when such a level is reached

```
SupervisorActor extends Actor  {
// if (msg instanceOf something)
// spawn child actor for every level in a graph
childActor.tell(node, getself());

How do I send messages to two childActors here when I have two nodes at the same level?

}
```

Comment: Actors communicate asynchronously, so you can create 2 actors and call tell twice to send each of them a message, they will process it concurrently.

Comment: would you explain with pseudo code?

Comment: OK I replied as an answer below

Answer (score 0):

Actors communicate asynchronously, so you can create 2 actors and call tell twice to send each of them a message, they will process it concurrently.

If you fo the following:

```
ActorRef child1 = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class), "child1");
ActorRef child2 = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class), "child2");
child1.tell(msg1, getself());
child2.tell(msg2, getself());
```

Both actors child1 and child2 will be created and process a message at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are asking to make multiple instance of the same actor.

You can define in your config file how many instance of your actor you want.

```
akka {
 /my-service {
  router = round-robin-pool // strategy how message will be served
  nr-of-instances = 3} // here you can define the number of instance
}
```